# Help with Selenium Maven Cargo

Tags: maven-2, selenium, maven-plugin

I am trying to use cargo to deploy and start my container (which works fine), and then use selenium to execute some UI tests.

Whenever I try to run (mvn clean integration-test), I get to the point where it says

```
Launching Selenium Server
Waiting for Selenium Server...
[INFO]Redirecting output to
[INFO]User extensions
```

But then my integration tests never get executed by surefire.  Any help is much appreciated.  It seems like the Selenium Server never gets started.

One quick note, I am using JUnit 4.4

I tried using ANT instead, to copy over the selenium-server and start selenium that way.  When I do that, my integration tests run, but I got the following error, which is why I was trying to use the selenium-maven-plugin.

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.3 sec <<< FAILURE!
testAllCriticalPagesLoadWithoutError(com.adminserver.pas.test.SimpleSmokeTest)  Time elapsed: 0.29 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: NUL
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:89)
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase.setUp(SeleneseTestBase.java:123)
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase.setUp(SeleneseTestBase.java:104)
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase.setUp(SeleneseTestCase.java:78)
 at com.adminserver.pas.test.BaseSeleniumTest.setUp(BaseSeleniumTest.java:69)
 at com.adminserver.pas.test.SimpleSmokeTest.setUp(SimpleSmokeTest.java:22)
 at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)
 at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase.runBare(SeleneseTestCase.java:212)
 at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
 at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
 at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
 at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
 at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
 at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:81)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:338)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:997)
```

Here is the relevant snippets in my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.0</version>

 <executions>
  <execution>
  <id>start-selenium</id>
  <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>start-server</goal>
  </goals>
 </execution>
 </executions>
 <configuration>
  <timeout>30</timeout>
  <background>true</background>
  <port>4444</port>
  <logOutput>true</logOutput>
  <verifyBrowser>*iexplore</verifyBrowser>
 </configuration>
 </plugin>
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
  <configuration>
  <skip>true</skip>
  <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>     
  </configuration>
  <executions>
   <execution>
    <phase>integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
     <goal>test</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
     <skip>false</skip>
    </configuration>
   </execution>
  </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Here is the output from the selenium server.log file:

```
11:35:51,542 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 1.5.0_19-b02
11:35:51,542 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] OS: Windows 2003 5.2 x86
11:35:51,592 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] v1.0.1 [2697], with Core v@VERSION@ [@REVISION@]
11:35:51,712 INFO  [org.mortbay.http.HttpServer] Version Jetty/5.1.x
11:35:51,712 INFO  [org.mortbay.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/,/]
11:35:51,722 INFO  [org.mortbay.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
11:35:51,722 INFO  [org.mortbay.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
11:35:51,732 INFO  [org.mortbay.http.SocketListener] Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
11:35:51,732 INFO  [org.mortbay.util.Container] Started org.mortbay.jetty.Server@bf32c
```

Comment: Your configuration looks ok to me, some things to check: Is IE installed to a non-standard location? What do you see if you run with the command-line option: *-Ddebug=true*

Comment: Nothing wrong with the selenium dependencies? Does `com.adminserver.pas.test.SimpleSmokeTest` run fine in your IDE?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I will check the IE installation and with the debug on.

Pascal, I don't know about the selenium dependencies.  Seemingly I just never get a "Selenium Server Started", which is what I would expect; it just hangs and doesn't come back.  When I used ant to run the selenium server at pre-integration-test, the tests ran at least but failed, I guess because I forked and spawned on the run of it.  It may have failed because the server wasn't started yet.

Comment: IE is installed at C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer

Comment: Not much help running this in debug mode...
.......
17:57:13,614 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] Selenium server running in debug mode.
17:57:13,755 INFO  [org.mortbay.http.HttpServer] Version Jetty/5.1.x
17:57:13,755 INFO  [org.mortbay.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/,/]
17:57:13,755 INFO  [org.mortbay.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
.....

Comment: Here is what I want to do:
1.  Deploy a war to a container
2.  Start up selenium server
3.  Run my junit tests 

I have tried a few different ways, using examples I found online, and it ain't working.

One other note, I am using JDK 1.5, and Maven 2.1.0

Comment: A quick update.  I removed the selenium-maven-plugin from my pom file, and started the selenium server separately in another process on my machine.  I am back to the exception "Could not start Selenium session: NUL" in the Surefire reports.  The funny thing is, I can right-click on the test in Eclipse and Run As Junit Test, and it will run just fine.  For some reason running the tests through maven is failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this finally to work.  Here are a couple of things that made this work:

1. JBOSS in the default startup started up its RMI Port on 4444 (that's the same one as Selenium ).  Not sure why I this wasn't more blatant obvious, maybe the sequence of runs in the maven file.  I added a port to the selenium-maven-plugin configuration, and added a system property of selenim.port to the surefire-plugin, PRESTO, it worked.
2. My plugin repository for Codehause (which publishes the selenium-maven-plugin) was set to snapshots (DOH).  I changed it to the release repo, that seemed to get things moving.
3. I changed the type of the project to "pom", so it didn't attempt to create a JAR
4. I don't know if it mattered or not, but I moved the surefire plugin to be AFTER the selenium-maven-plugin

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution to your problem (especially the port conflict between selenium and JBoss, highly valuable)