# maven cargo and selenium

Tags: java, maven-2, tomcat, selenium, maven-cargo

i use maven cargo and selenium for automation. here is the code:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <wait>false</wait>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                    <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>
                            http://mirrors.enquira.co.uk/apache/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.30/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.30.zip
                        </url>
                        <installDir>${installDir}</installDir>
                    </zipUrlInstaller>
                    <output>
                        ${project.build.directory}/tomcat6x.log
                    </output>
                    <log>${project.build.directory}/cargo.log</log>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <home>
                        ${project.build.directory}/tomcat6x/container
                    </home>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
                        <cargo.servlet.port>8081</cargo.servlet.port>
                    </properties>
                    <files>
                        <copy>
                          <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/datasource.properties</file>
                          <todir>webapps</todir>
                          <configfile>true</configfile>
                          <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        </copy>
                    </files>
                    <properties>
                       <customMessage>${catalina.home}</customMessage>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>configure</goal>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <deployer>
                            <deployables>
                                <deployable>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <type>war</type>
                                    <pingURL>**the url**</pingURL>
                                    <pingTimeout>180000</pingTimeout>
                                    <properties>
                                        <context>**war-name**</context>
                                    </properties>
                                </deployable>
                            </deployables>
                        </deployer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

but as the war started getting bigger the pingtimeout started to increase, i dont want to use ping timeout, but i am being forced to at the moment, as deployment takes a bit of time and selenium does not wait if the pingtimeout is not mentioned.

is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Could http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498967/help-with-selenium-maven-cargo be related?

Answer (score 1):

What about using Jetty? The maven-jetty-plugin will wait until your webapp is loaded. Alternatively, you can use the tomcat-maven-plugin and its deploy goal to deploy your webapp to a running Tomcat instance through the Tomcat Manager. This plugin will also wait with the execution (and therefore the launch of your Selenium tests) until the war is deployed.

This is my configuration. It will launch Jetty, deploy the application, launch Selenium, launch Selenium tests and finally quits all the servers:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <contextPath>/</contextPath>
          <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <background>true</background>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start-selenium</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>start-server</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop-selenium</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop-server</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>selenium-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <skip>false</skip>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>none</exclude>
              </excludes>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*SeleniumTest.java</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```